# Adding multiple one to many relationships to one table using EF

Tags: c#, mysql, angularjs, entity-framework

I am trying to add another one to many relationship to a table(one) that is already created to a new table(many).  I have another one that is currently working so I tried to replicate it but was unsuccessful.
Here is my Context:

```
public class SkillResourceCenterAppContext : DbContext
{
    public SkillResourceCenterAppContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Persons> Persons { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }

    public DbSet<PersonSkill> PersonSkills { get; set; }

    public DbSet<PersonExperience> PersonExperience { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Persons>().HasMany(x => x.PersonSkills).WithRequired(x => x.Person).HasForeignKey(u => u.PersonNumber).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        //New Line for new model
        modelBuilder.Entity<Persons>().HasMany(x => x.PersonExperiences).WithRequired(x => x.Person).HasForeignKey(u => u.PersonNumber);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Skill>().HasMany(x => x.PersonSkills).WithRequired(x => x.Skill).HasForeignKey(u => u.SkillCodeID);
    }
}
```

Here is my model I am trying to add:

```
 public class PersonExperience
 {
    public PersonExperience() { }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string ExperienceTitle { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int PersonNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Persons Person { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the model of the table I am trying to create another one to many relationship with:

```
public class Persons
{
    public Persons() { }

    [Key]
    public int PersonNumber { get; set; }

    public string IdName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string PersonPosition { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PersonSkill> PersonSkills { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PersonExperience> PersonExperiences { get; set; }
}
```

The rest was working until I tried to run this new Migration and update the database.  Now every time the code accesses the PersonExperience table it throws A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies error.  I have tried adding Foreign Key annotation to the Model but it doesn't work.  I have tried the WillCascadeOnDelete and nothing seems to be working.  The closest I got was adding the ScriptIgnore annotation to the virtual person in the PersonExperiences model but then the Person value isn't showing in the angular ui grid.  And currently the database is showing the PersonExperiences table as having the Foreign Key as PersonNumber.  Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: You must change the serializer settings to ignore circular references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using a Select statement to retrieve the records.  It worked and displayed in my grid after changing the where clause to Select the data I needed.

```
result = db.Persons.Where(x => x.Active && x.PersonNumber.ToString() == userStringQuery.Id)
                       .Select(c => new { ID = c.PersonNumber, Value = c.FullName }).OrderBy(c => c.Value);
```